# Kafka Producer Config Configurations for Logging Purpose

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Hi I want to use kafka for logging purpose
In my case I want that my system avaliability does not effect from kafka process

For that reason I set ack to 0 ,reduce max_ms,delivery_timeout,request_timeout to minimal values like 1 second.

Is there any other config should I set in this scenario.
Because if any time pass via over kafka it affects my system in negative way

Can anyone suggest strategy about this scenario